# php stop sql query from running every time on refresh

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my php script, I used a sql query to create a table, but after creating the table every subsequent refresh will return an error message stating table is already created. I know its already created but how do I stop query from running a second time on refresh if its already ran?

php script:

```
<?php
include_once ".env.php";
include_once "template.php";

html_top('School Database');
// open connection
$conn = mysqli_connect(host,username,password,database_name);

// verify connection
if (!$conn)
exit("<p class='error'>Connection Error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "</p>");

// create table
$sql = "create table students2 (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    first varchar(20), 
    last varchar(20), 
    dob date, primary key (id))";

$create = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if ($create)
    echo "Created";
else
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);

html_bottom();
```

Comment: instead of create table you could do `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` but preferable dont run it everytime, you only need to create a table once 99% of the time

Comment: Why would your code even create a table? That's a one time activity done by the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DDL commands, such as `create table`, should be in a separate file which is called only one time in the initialization step.
This is the formal way to be away from errors.

Another way that may help, but not efficient, is by using: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Students2(....)`.

```
// create table 
$sql = "create table if not exists students2 ( 
id int not null auto_increment, 
first varchar(20), 
last varchar(20), 
dob date, 
primary key (id))";
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a logical error when using create or alter tables commands more than one, or when using them in the pages or functions that frequently used or refreshed.
In your case there are many solutions, but the perfect solution is to separate the creation commands from other code.

Or you can use the (if exists ) when creating any table as guys answered you.

Comment: Hi @nm5acc, If you provide concrete examples to demonstrate your point then this answer will be more useful.  Often when developers visit StackOverflow they are looking for clear extracts that describe the solution or workaround and a generalised answer tends to get ignored.  Please try to remember that a good, clear answer provides assistance to future developers years from now, not just the author of the question, and can still benefit from future upvotes.